# Is it possible to get pointers to the real and imaginary parts of a cuDoubleComplex?

Tags: cuda

Consider a `cuDoubleComplex` array `a` in device memory. Is it possible get pointers to the real and imaginary parts of `a` without allocating and doing a deep copy into two new `double` arrays?

something like this:

```
real_a = //points to real part of a
imag_a = //points to imaginary part of a
```

instead of something like:

```
/*allocate real_a and imag_a here */
    for(int j=0; j<numElements; j++){
        real_a[j]= a[j].x;
        imag_a[j]= a[j].y;
}
```

<strike>[CUDA does have something like this for numbers](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/cuDoubleComplex.html), but not for arrays/pointers.</strike>

The reason is that I would like to be able to call cuBLAS `D` rather than `Z` functions on the real and imaginary parts separately. For example,

```
cublasDgemm(...,real_a,...,somearray,...,anotherarray,...)
```

Comment: Welll...all of the imaginary parts (likewise for real) should be spaced on a fixed stride, so you could theoretically compute the address of each as `base + index * stride` for an iterator...Maybe we could help better if you told us why you need the components of the complex number array split into two arrays, vs. just leaving them in `a[]` and accessing as needed.

Comment: Ok, I actually need them as contiguous blocks because I will be calling cuBLAS functions on them. I've added more details to the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: Note what you linked to is JCUDA documentation and that is basically just for interoperability between java and the C types that CUBLAS/CUFFT use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible get pointers to the real and imaginary parts of a
>   without allocating and doing a deep copy into two new double arrays?

That can be done:

```
double* real_a = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&a[0].x); //points to real part of a
double* imag_a = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&a[0].y); //points to imaginary part of a
```

but note that you need to use a stride of 2 when accessing the pointers to get the correct real or imaginary elements.

> The reason is that I would like to be able to call cuBLAS D rather
>   than Z functions on the real and imaginary parts separately.

This will work with BLAS functions which operate on your real or imaginary pointers as vectors, because those BLAS routines allow a stride to be passed (which must be two in this case).

> For example,
>
> `cublasDgemm(...,real_a,...,somearray,...,anotherarray,...)`

That won't work with the pointers you can directly get as I have shown here. BLAS functions which would treat the array as a matrix do support strided source and destination data, but that stride is applied to the start of each column with the flattened matrix, but not to elements within a column, which is what you would need to make this work correctly.

Comment: Great suggestion. I suppose for the level 3 BLAS functions the only options is a deep copy?

Comment: If you are going to use a closed source library modelled on the conventional BLAS (like CUBLAS) then a deep copy is probably the only way. If you were willing to modify the source of a DGEMM kernel to use a strided pointer class instead of plain pointers to double, then you could potentially do what you want. The question would then be one of performance. Is a naive GEMM with strided memory access faster than an optimal GEMM with a deep copy. Benchmarking holds the answer to that question.